# Apply same id on different objects and animate them separately (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Let's say I have a row of divs like here: jsfiddle.net/AlphaCrack/veuc80he/1/

I wan't to animate them separately but keeping the same id because I may have to create tons of divs like those and I don't wan't to create tons of css ids. As you can see applying the same id on multiple elements will affect only the first one. Why? What can I do to animate them separately with the same id.

The HTML:

```
<div id="TEST">
</div>
<div id="TEST">
</div>
<div id="TEST">
</div>
<div id="TEST">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#TEST
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #252525;
    border: 1px solid #AAFF00;
    float: left;
}
```

The jQuery:

```
$("#TEST").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#TEST").stop();
    $("#TEST").animate({"height":"200px"},200);
});

$("#TEST").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#TEST").stop();
    $("#TEST").animate({"height":"100px"},200);
});
```

Actually I have tons of animating frames (with same id) holding each of my images from my database. And I need to animate each frame separately when I hover the picture.

Comment: Ok sorry. Just a minute.

Comment: Using `id` twice or more usually isn't recommendable. Isn't it possible for you to use classes?

Comment: I highly recommend you read a book on HTML and CSS. Class is very basic. In my opinion you should not really be using JavaScript if you don't know the basics of HTML. It will lead you to many many errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, having duplicate `id` attributes within a single page is invalid as they must be unique. This is why only the first element was being affected by your events. Use a class instead.

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

Then in your JS you can use the common class to stop all animation on the `.test` elements, and `this` to reference only the one which raised the event.

```
$(".test").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".test").stop();
    $(this).animate({ "height": "200px" }, 200);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(".test").stop();
    $(this).animate({ "height": "100px" }, 200);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/veuc80he/5/)

You could also simplify your code to use `hover`, which would negate the need for `stop()` which was causing the occasional mis-alignment when hovering quickly over the elements:

```
$(".test").hover(
    function() { $(this).animate({ "height": "200px" }, 200); }, 
    function() { $(this).animate({ "height": "100px" }, 200); }
);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/veuc80he/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have DOMElements with the same ID unfortunatly, that won't work for jQuery.

You must use classes.

```
$(".TEST").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({"height":"200px"},200);
});

$(".TEST").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({"height":"100px"},200);
});
```

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ruxhighwind/veuc80he/6/

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is use some other sort of jquery selector, maybe based on a parent, much like this:

```
$(".parent > div").each(function(i){

  $(this).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({"height":"200px"},200);
  });

  $(this).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({"height":"100px"},200);
  });

});
```

And wrap them in a parent div! Just tested in your fiddle and works fine! But keep in mind that having multiple ids of the same value is bad form.